# how to get rid of useless, duplicates, backups files from a webroot folder

Tags: php, web-crawler

I just recover an old website full of useless file (index2.php, index_bkup.php, test.php...), and I wonder how to make a list of these...

Solution can be either server side or client side (but I can't do too much thing serverside)...

As I say the site is pretty old and use a lot of include() function.

Thx for ideas !

Comment: What is your question? Do you mean unused files? How would a program detect whether a file is unused or not when it's a public-facing resource? This needs more info.

Comment: **Manual labour.** Using a simple web-crawler won't cut it. You need an AI to reliably differentiate needed from unneeded files. Just looking for `backup` or `test` or worse `2` numeric suffixes will lead to false positives. This is not what you want.

Comment: Manual labour: thx but I dont' want to go so far! The main idea is to make a crossover beetween, let s say a webcrawler and some kind of apache access.log, and the results will be all the files that can be somehow used by the website...But I'm not sure if a webcrawler can handle form...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this should be automated, as it could delete files that *look like* garbage.

You could do...

```
$files = glob('path/*.php');

$files = preg_grep('/\d+\.php$/', $files);

foreach($files as $file) {
   unlink($file);
}
```

This will get all PHP files in a directory and delete ones which have a number before the extension, for example `index2.php`.

It won't match `test.php`, but you could modify it to.

Either way, it may be better using `grep` to find these, and then determining on a file by file basis whether they should be deleted or not.

**Please backup first**.